# using sed or awk to find and append lines with same IDs in a file

Tags: design-patterns, sed, awk

I have some files in the following format { *ID Type Size Nodes* }, for example:

```
1234 P 1 56
2212 P 2 45-46
1234 F 
2567 P 3 90,99,101
2212 F
2567 F
```

where every P type line has only one matching F type line with the same ID and the IDs are different for each pair.

I would like to be able to search over the file and for each line of type P, find the matching type F line with the same ID and then append the "Size" and "Nodes" values from the P type line.

Is this possible? 
I can think of a way to do it in bash using associative arrays, but I was hoping that sed/awk might have some nifty little trick for something like this, but I don't have the right words to search for it/look it up. I know that you can hold patterns, my main problem is figuring out the best way to search for the different IDs.

Comment: no tricks.. just use the same logic. does the order of lines matter?

Comment: I'm guessing the order _is_ important, otherwise you could just change `F` to `P` and disregard the old `F` lines.

Comment: yes, the order is important, changes need to be made in place, but P always comes before F..sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the line order changing the simplest approach is:

```
$ awk '$2=="P"{print;$2="F";print}' file
1234 P 1 56
1234 F 1 56
2212 P 2 45-46
2212 F 2 45-46
2567 P 3 90,99,101
2567 F 3 90,99,101
```

That is the order of the `F` lines change to be printed after the occurrence of the `P` line (the order of `P` lines is not changed).

If you don't want the order changing but guarantee the `P` line occurs first then:

```
$ awk '$2=="P"{a[$1]=$3FS$4}{print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file
1234 P 1 56
2212 P 2 45-46
1234 F 1 56
2567 P 3 90,99,101
2212 F 2 45-46
2567 F 3 90,99,101
```

Other wise you have two approaches, buffering or passing the file twice, here is a pass twice solution:

```
$ awk '$2=="P"{a[$1]=$3FS$4}FNR!=NR{print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file file
1234 P 1 56
2212 P 2 45-46
1234 F 1 56
2567 P 3 90,99,101
2212 F 2 45-46
2567 F 3 90,99,101
```

This will be fine unless your actaul files are really large in which case a buffered approach will be better:

```
$ awk '$2=="P"{a[$1]=$3FS$4}{b[NR]=$0;k[NR]=$1}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print b[i],a[k[i]]}' file
1234 P 1 56
2212 P 2 45-46
1234 F 1 56
2567 P 3 90,99,101
2212 F 2 45-46
2567 F 3 90,99,101
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter and you have matching F lines for every P, you can:

```
grep ' P ' file; grep ' P ' file | sed 's/ P / F /'
```

Comment: This will cause confusing when wanting to redirect the output.

Comment: I don't think your comment adds any clarification for new users. Beside I don't think this is a great approach in general, something like `sed -n '/ P /{p;s/ P / F /p}' file` is better. `grep` is not needed with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Usage `awk -f app.awk file.dat  file.dat`

**app.awk:**

```
FNR==NR && $2 == "P" {
    id=$1
    $1=$2=""
    aux[id]=$0
}

FNR!=NR && $2 == "F" {
    $0 = $0 aux[$1]
    $1=$1
}

FNR!=NR {
    print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2=="F"{$3=s[$1];$4=n[$1]}{s[$1]=$3}n[$1]=$4' file
```

this will preserve the order, provided `P` line comes before `F` line. thanks to sudo_O +

Comment: thanks, I was wondering how is it done usually. I am not so familiar to awk.

Comment: This use of empty blocks is strange, this is more standard `awk '{a[$1]++}a[$1]==2{$3=s[$1];$4=n[$1]}{s[$1]=$3}n[$1]=$4' file`. This only preserved order in the `P` line comets first that is.